# I get error using tesseract package in python

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am trying to read the text in a cheque using pytesseract OCR. I have installed the required python packages required for this task e.g. pip install pytesseract.

However when I try to use the package to read the file I get the following error:

```
 pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='eng')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-d7d9f430493b>", line 1, in <module>
    pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='eng')

  File "C:\Users\BRIGHT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 294, in image_to_string
    return run_and_get_output(*args)

  File "C:\Users\BRIGHT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 202, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\BRIGHT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 172, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()

TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

This error dosent make sense because I actually import the package without getting any error. But when I try to use it I get the error.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

im=Image.open('BritishChequeAnnotated.jpg')
text=pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='eng')
```

Comment: are you sure you are running your python file with same version you are editing with? I've seen lots of people develop in anaconda and then run in their other python

Comment: Yes I am doing so.

Comment: The thing that you're "successfully importing" in Python is just a wrapper. A bridge which connects Python to Tesseract that you should have installed on your machine too. You have to install the actual Tesseract on your pc: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/4.0-with-LSTM#400-alpha-for-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for tesseract makes this clear.

https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

```
# If you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH, include the following:
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install teserract executable file and include the path into the  program then it won't gives any error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you clarify, perhaps with some example code? It's also a good idea to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).